# PHP Sum multi-dimentional array date interval, for an employee clock

Tags: php, arrays, date, sum

time is DateTime Object formatted as:

```
$time = $date->format("%H:%i:%s");
```

I'm trying to sum hours and group employees.

I have:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 2
            [time] => 00:0:17
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 1
            [time] => 00:0:4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 2
            [time] => 02:0:0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 3
            [time] => 02:0:0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 3
            [time] => 01:0:0
        )

)
```

And I need something like, grouped and sum:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 2
            [totalTime] => 02:0:17
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 1
            [totalTime] => 00:0:4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 3
            [totalTime] => 03:0:0
        )

)
```

Any thoughts? Maybe convert time to UNIX and manipulate from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want *something like* like the desired output, perhaps this will do:

```
foreach($array as $value){
  if(!isset($data[$value['employee']])){
    $data[$value['employee']] = 0;
  }

  $parsed = date_parse($value['time']);
  $data[$value['employee']] += $parsed['hour'] * 3600 + $parsed['minute'] * 60 + $parsed['second'];
}

print_r($data);
```

Instead of creating a multidimensional array, `$data` will have the key of the `employee` and the value of the total time in seconds.

Obviously you can convert seconds very easily to a format if you so please.